# Deriving definitive function of single variable from system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following system of four equations:

$x_1+x_2+x_3=K$

$A\cdot x_3=y$

$B\cdot x_2=y$

$C\cdot x_1=y$

From these four equations I would like to derive a function for y of A,B,C and K as such:

$f(A,B,C,K)=y$

How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: What does $*$ mean here?

Comment: I am using ∗ as multiplier

Comment: Then substitute $x_1, x_2, x_3$ if $(A, B, C)\neq (0, 0, 0)$. Otherwise, $y = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me firstly enumerate your equalities:

$$\begin{array}{cr}
x_1+x_2+x_3=K & (1)\\
A\cdot x_3=y & (2)\\
B\cdot x_2=y & (3)\\
C\cdot x_1=y & (4)\end{array}$$

By multiplying (2)-(4), we obtain

$$\begin{array}{cr}
A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot x_3=B \cdot C \cdot y & (5)\\
A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot x_2=A \cdot C \cdot y & (6)\\
A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot x_1=A \cdot B \cdot y & (7)\end{array}$$

Thus, by adding (5)-(7), we have

$$
(B \cdot C + A \cdot C + A \cdot B)\cdot y=A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) \overset{(1)}{=} A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot K \quad (8)
$$

Now, we distinguish between two cases:

**Case 1**: $BC + AC + AB \neq 0$. Then we can rearrange (8) to
$$ y = \frac{ABCK}{BC + AC + AB} $$
**Case 2**: $BC + AC + AB = 0$. Then by (8) it follows that $ABCK = 0$, so one of $A,B,C,K$ has to be zero. If $A,B$ or $C$ are zero, then (2), (3) or (4) imply $y=0$. Otherwise, we can assume $A,B,C \neq 0, K=0$.

But I have to admit: at this point I'm stuck as well. I tried to rearrange (2)-(4):
$$\begin{array}{cr}
x_3=\frac{y}{A} & (9)\\
x_3=\frac{y}{B} & (10)\\
x_3=\frac{y}{C} & (11)\end{array}$$
So, by (1) and $K=0$: $\left(\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{C}\right)y = 0$

Sadly, because $ABC \neq 0$, if we divide the case-2-equation we get $\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{C} = 0$. So at this point I don't know how to continue.

**Note**: This answers assumes we are working over a field.